# ios Mapkit: Change from hybrid to map is ignored when testing on device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, mapkit

I am testing an iPhone app that include mapkit. I have changed the map view type from 'hybrid' to 'map'. It works fine in the simulator but when I test on device the iPhone ignores the change and shows me the 'hybrid' mapview.

If I try to profile on the device it works fine.

Any ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us some code? Can't help without more information.

Comment: @mjisrawi. I have changed the setting in interface builder.

Comment: Then make sure you've properly connected the map view to a corresponding IBOutlet declared in your view controller.

Comment: @mijsrawi - I removed the referencing outlet connection to the map view and added it again - and then it worked. Thanks for leading me in the right direction.

Comment: Sure...maybe I should've posted this as an answer so you can accept it? haha

Comment: I just added it as an answer, can you please accept that so the question appears as closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you've properly connected the map view to a corresponding IBOutlet declared in your view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below codes, I think you have not set the type of mapview properly, Here you can choose the map type which you want.

```
map.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
```

OR

```
map.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
```

OR

```
map.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
```